# Automatic Added By / Registered by when adding/register a user in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, admin, registration

We have a test system and we want to add a automatically fill up it to the SQL the "Added By / Registered by: " depends on what Username he have.

We want to track who add this item.

**Example:**
My friend logged in to our system and he's ID number is admin05, so my friene will add new item. Our add item for consists of Item name & item code. So I  fill it up and sumbit but I as the head admin I want to see in our database who add that item.

***Another example:** 
We have 5 admins in our system 1 SuperAdmin(me) and 4 admins. Usually the 4 admins are the one who are in-charge in adding new items. So as superadmin If I see the list of all items I can see who add this products.

Thank you.

Comment: Provide the sample code you tried for this?

Comment: while inserting the data, insert current date and time to DB

Comment: I don't have any code yet. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Edited the post for more samples.

Comment: sample view of the system 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ4xG.jpg

Comment: A foreign key in the Post table that points to the table of admins. With every new post you refer the admin that created it. When fetching data use joins to pull the post as well as the creator at once ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a page with the create new item form, let say `createItem.php`. And submit that form to a PHP page, let say `saveItem.php`. Now when user submit the form from `createItem.php` it will go to `saveItem.php` page where you will receive all your form data with `$_POST` variable. Make sure to make the form `method` to `POST` in `createItem.php`.

So now you have to build all your data that you want to save in DB.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (itemID, itemName, addedBy, addedOn) VALUES ($_POST['itemID'], $_POST['itemName'], $_SESSION['userName'], now());
```

NOTE: `itemID` is the item id field name in `createItem.php`, `itemName` is the item name field name in `createItem.php`, `$_SESSION['userName']` is the logged in user name stored in session.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Sorry I'm still new in PHP MySQL, 
Actually here is my my visualization of my problem:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ4xG.jpg

Here is my understanding to your answer.
I will have 2 tables : ( 1 table for accountinfo, 1 table for Items )
so i will have join table right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in `accountinfo` table you have user information. And when you save item record in DB for `addedBy` column you have to store user id which is primary key from `accountinfo` table. So now you have to do a join query for these 2 table to get all information.